# Are there higher-order vector fields (analogously to higher-order differential forms)?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, differential-forms, vector-bundles

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold.

First,

- a differential $1$-form on $M$ is a smooth section of the cotangent bundle $T^*M$ of $M$
- a vector field on $M$ is a smooth section of the tangent bundle $TM$ of $M$.

Now,

- a differential $k$-form on $M$ is a smooth section of the $k$-th exterior power $\Lambda^k (T^*M)$ of $T^*M$.

So, what do you call a smooth section of the $k$-th exterior power $\Lambda^k(TM)$ of $TM$? Would it be a "higher-order" vector field? Specifically, is it a [multivector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivector) "field", in the spirit of [geometric algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra)?

(Please correct any mistakes.)

Comment: Note that to the best of my knowledge, what are called higher order tangents are duals to $I_x/I_x^k$ (as opposed to $I_x/I_x^2$, which are tangent vectors), where $I_x$ is the ideal of smooth functions vanishing at $x$. Which are decidedly not the same as multivectors, but rather, objects representing higher order ODEs.

Comment: I saw several people call it poly-vector fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes people consider "multi-vector" fields, ie section of $\wedge ^k TM$. Fields of "bi-vectors" are particularly useful in the study of Poisson structures, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_manifold.

On these fields, Nijenhuis defined an operation called bracket (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nijenhuis%E2%80%93Richardson_bracket).